# How can i solve 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command issue?

Tags: boost, mingw, msys

I am trying to build libs for boost using Msys. I am referring this link https://github.com/moritz-wundke/Boost-for-Android/blob/master/README.md
While following this process I am getting error

> Building Boost.Build engine 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or >external command, operable program or batch file.

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Could you add more details? More output, the script that you're executing and so on...

Comment: Script I am using is build-android.sh. That script along with other files is present in Link I have shared above. I am running this in windows PC using MSYS. ERROR:- **Performing boost bootstrapBuilding Boost.Build engine'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.Failed to build Boost.Build engine.Please consult bootstrap.log for further diagnostics.** cl.exe is from MSVC it seems but I am not using MSVC. Some code must be edited in script so that it will not take cl.exe and instead it should take whatever mingW or ndk is providing(I am not sure)

Comment: Try setting `CXX=clang++`. I assume you execute the *.sh* script from *MSys* environment. Also when providing extra (important) details don't do it via comments, but edit the question instead.

Comment: Hi @CristiFati I am able to solve cl.exe problem but after that I am getting this error : **C:\Users\503092106\Downloads\Boost-for-Android-master\Boost-for-Android-master\boost_1_69_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
ERROR: Failed to build boost for android for armeabi-v7a!**

Comment: Hmm, only from that I can't tell what it is. Seems like something inside a custom build system used by *Boost*. Increase its output (*-v* argument). But that seems to be a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the *Boost* build system figured out that it runs on *Win* and attempted to use *VStudio* compiler (*cl.exe*) by default. Since its parent dir is not in *${PATH}*, the invocation attempt failed with the above error.

Explicitly "tell" the build system (*make*) what compiler to use. That is commonly done by setting the environment variable ***CXX*** ([[GNU]:  Variables Used by Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html)) before running *make*:

```
CXX=clang++
```

To avoid any further surprises, make sure that *clang++*'s dir is also present in *${PATH}*.

Comment: Did this answer your compiler related question? Regarding the other issue you ran into, were you able to fix it? Or you asked a different question?